# DDMS Not showing my logs

Tags: android, logging, ddms

I'm having an issue with DDMS.
System logs are appearing fine, but my own logs aren't showing up.

I'm trying to view the logs in ddms.exe.

I've tried restarting adb, stop/start adb, restart ddms, restart emulator, recreate avd.
Nothing has had an effect. I've tested this with two different apps.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** same issue in logcat.
No filters selected
I've restarted the computer

Comment: Are they showing up in the LogCat?

Comment: Do you accidentally have any filters selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to mention that i'm using a tool called Kony. It is a "write once deploy everywhere" mobile development environment.

When the app is being compiled in release mode (which I was unaware of) all print statements are removed.

Had this not been the case, some or all of the previous suggestions would have worked, i'm sure.

Comment: Can you please share your experience on the reality of "write once deploy everywhere" of Kony platform.

Comment: http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/robert-szabo/the-truth-about-all-one-solution

Answer (score 1):

As i remember you have to make you app debuggable ("android:debuggable=true") in your manifest file. Or you can find your app in DDMS but can't get access for your own logs?

Comment: the app is debuggable and I can see it in DDMS... I've clicked it, refreshed the list, cleared the logs.

Answer (score 1):

can you try the command:

```
> adb logcat -s "TAG"
```

on a terminal/cmd line ?
here "TAG" is the name of the tag which you are giving in your Log

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the device and then ur application in DDMS and then viewing logs ?

Comment: Correct. that is what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above.

It is true that the value we are trying to print will not be logged to the console but it is not strictly removal of print statements. Kony.print get executed .

This observation can be checked by building in release mode and trying to print and undefined value, you will get type error thrown.